# Issue on Listing Folder Names in Specific Directory

Tags: php

I am using following code to list all folders on a specific directory path (here it is **audio** folder)

```
<?php 
    $directory = "audio/";
    $files = glob($directory . "*");
    foreach($files as $file){
        if(is_dir($file))
        {
            echo '<option value="'.$file.'">'.$file.'</option>';
        }
    }
?>
```

but in the result I am getting the audio/ before the name of all files as:

[image]

can you please let me know why this is happening and how I can fix it? Thansk

Comment: `basename()` http://php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[basename()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php)

```
echo '<option value="'. basename($file) . '">' . basename($file) . '</option>';
```

Also, just return the directories so you don't need to check:

```
$files = glob($directory . "*", GLOB_ONLYDIR);

foreach($files as $file){
    $file = basename($file);
    echo '<option value="'.$file.'">'.$file.'</option>';
}
```

Comment: Thanks AbraCadaver , I have to wait 8 min to accept the answer.